# Select unique Records based on a column by conditionally removing the other record having same column value based on some other coumn in sql

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am developing an Android app in which I am using the Room persistence library. In one of the Tables (Room Entity), I have a case where I want to select unique Records based on a column by conditionally removing the other record having the same column value based on some other column.

Consider the following table as a base.

| S_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending |
| 1 | Rejected |
| 3 | Approved |
| 4 | Approved |
| 5 | Pending |
| 6 | Rejected |
| 7 | Rejected |

the expected result of the SQL query where I want a record with '`Rejected'` status to be removed from results if its S_ID collides with another 'Pending' status record

| S_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending |
| 3 | Approved |
| 4 | Approved |
| 5 | Pending |
| 6 | Rejected |
| 7 | Rejected |

what I have tried so far:

```
select DISTINCT s_id OR s_id = 0, * from TABLE1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation for this:

```
select s_id, min(status) as status
from table_id
group by s_id;
```

This uses the fact that alphabetical ordering is used for `max()` and `'Pending' < 'Rejecdted'`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I used what you have suggested as below: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE S_ID in (select s_id, min(status) as status from table1 group by s_id) ORDER BY status = \"Rejected\" DESC   but this gave the SQL error (sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1)

Comment: @RKB . . . What I suggest is the code in the answer.  It addresses the question that you asked.

Answer (score 2):

I think You can try below query :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.S_ID in (SELECT S_ID FROM table1 GROUP BY S_ID HAVING COUNT(S_ID)>0) and table1.[status]<>'Rejected'
```

Edited :

```
SELECT table1.S_ID, 
(select Alias.[Status] from Table1 Alias where Alias.S_ID=table1.S_ID  
and ((COUNT(table1.S_ID)>1 and Alias.[Status]<>'Rejected') or COUNT(table1.S_ID)=1) 
) as [Status]
FROM table1 GROUP BY S_ID HAVING COUNT(S_ID)>0
```

Comment: thanks for this, but this is returning the results where all the 'Rejected' records are removed, what I want is only omit those 'Rejected' records whose S_ID collides with that of 'Pending' status records.  It should return other 'Rejected' records in the result. I have edited my question for more clarity about the result.

Comment: can You please try below query:
SELECT table1.S_ID, 
(select Alias.[Status] from Table1 Alias where Alias.S_ID=table1.S_ID  
and ((COUNT(table1.S_ID)>1 and Alias.[Status]<>'Rejected') or COUNT(table1.S_ID)=1) 
) as [Status]
FROM table1 GROUP BY S_ID HAVING COUNT(S_ID)>0

Comment: I used your edited query as below: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.S_ID in (SELECT table1.S_ID, 
(select Alias.[Status] from Table1 Alias where Alias.S_ID=table1.S_ID  
and ((COUNT(table1.S_ID)>1 and Alias.[Status]<>'Rejected') or COUNT(table1.S_ID)=1) 
) as [Status]
FROM table1 GROUP BY S_ID HAVING COUNT(S_ID)>0) ORDER BY STATUS = "Rejected" DESC     but this gave SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (misuse of aggregate function COUNT())

Comment: You only take edited query? like below:
SELECT table1.S_ID, 
(select Alias.[Status] from Table1 Alias where Alias.S_ID=table1.S_ID  
and ((COUNT(table1.S_ID)>1 and Alias.[Status]<>'Rejected') or COUNT(table1.S_ID)=1) 
) as [Status]
FROM table1 GROUP BY S_ID