# how to get records from a result of a subquery which matches a value of a column in SQL?

Tags: android, sql

In my Android app, I am using the Room persistence library. In one of the Tables (Room Entity).

Consider the following table.

| S_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending |
| 1 | Rejected |
| 3 | Approved |
| 4 | Approved |
| 5 | Pending |
| 6 | Rejected |
| 7 | Rejected |
| 8 | Approved |
| 9 | Rejected |

the expected result of the SQL sub-query where I want a record with '`Rejected'` status to be removed from results if its S_ID collides with another 'Pending' status record. This was sorted in my previous question:
[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152209/select-unique-records-based-on-a-column-by-conditionally-removing-the-other-reco)

| S_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending |
| 3 | Approved |
| 4 | Approved |
| 5 | Pending |
| 6 | Rejected |
| 7 | Rejected |
| 8 | Approved |
| 9 | Rejected |

Now, the outer query should give the following result with records only with '`Rejected'` status.

| S_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | Rejected |
| 7 | Rejected |
| 9 | Rejected |

This result is required to satisfy a use case where I need to show the records based on a selected 'Status' by the user. for example, if user selects 'Approved', then the app will show all 'Apprvoed' records. But in case of 'Rejected', I need to show all rejected records except those whose s_id conflict with that of 'Pending'. I also want a count of such records additionlally.

Comment: Please explain the logic for the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have edited my question explaining the use case of the results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the rows after the last `'Pending'` status:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.s_id > (select max(t2.s_id) from t t2 where t2.status = 'Pending');
```

I don't even think you need to remove the "conflicts" if this is the logic you want.

Comment: No, I don't want rows after the last 'Pending' status, What I want is all those 'Rejected' records except that conflicting ones with 'Pending'. I have edited my question for more clarity.